# Optimised array shift method

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` holding `NSStrings` e.g. `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`

I would like to be able to shift elements with wrapping.

So e.g. move 1 to the centre, shifting all elements, wrapping the remaining ones (that cross the bounds) to the start again, and vice versa e.g. 10 to the centre.

`{7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` and `{6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Is there an optimised `sort` method like this already existing?

Comment: I think we can do that in linear time with one `for` loop, one for the first `k` elements say 1-6 and next for remaining `m` elements i.e 7-10. and `k+m = n` which is size of the array. But i am not aware of any standard algorithm as such.

Comment: @PraveenS - `trueIndex = (offset + index) % array.count`.  I think that's better than linear time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient approach would be to create a wrapper object which maintains the current "origin" of the array and re-interprets indexes by adding that origin, modulo the length.  In fact, if the array is only accessed in a handful of places this is easily done with 1-2 lines of code in-line.

```
-(id)objectForIndex:(NSInteger) index {
    NSInteger realIndex = (origin + index) % array.count;
    return [array objectAtIndex:realIndex];
}
```

(If this extends NS(Mutable)Array then "array" is "super".  If only a wrapper then "array" is an instance var.  "origin" is an instance var/property in either case.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm unaware of any methods on `NSArray` for this, but:

```
static NSArray *shiftArray(NSArray *array, NSInteger pos)
{
    NSInteger length = [array count];
    NSArray *post = [array subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){ .location = length - pos, .length = pos }];
    NSArray *pre = [array subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){ .location = 0, .length = length - pos}];
    return [post arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:pre];
}
```

e.g.:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I"];
NSLog(@"array = %@",shiftArray(array, 4));
```

Should do what you describe.

Logs to the console:

```
array = (
    F,
    G,
    H,
    I,
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E
)
```

Likely not performant.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSArray*)shiftForward:(BOOL)forward withbits:(int)bit
{
    NSInteger length = [array count];
    NSArray *right;
    NSArray *left;

    if (forward) {
        //code for right shift
        right = [array subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){ .location = length - bit, .length = bit }];
        left = [array subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){ .location = 0, .length = length - bit}];
        return [right arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:left];
    }else{
        //code for left shift
        left = [array subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){ .location =0, .length = bit }];
        right= [array subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){ .location = bit, .length = length - bit}];
        return [right arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:left];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    array = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9"];
    NSLog(@"array is %@",[self shiftForward:YES withbits:3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

surely if you are shifting by `N` elements that must wrap around all you would do is take the last `N` array elements and stick them at the front?

and if you are shifting the other way, take the front and put at the back.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating is essentially done by taking N elements from one end of the array and putting them on the other end instead. You could do this with immutable arrays if you wanted, but mutable arrays offer a slightly cleaner implementation.

For rotate left, the simplest way is probably just:

```
// Make sure we don't overrun the array if the rotation is larger.
numberOfObjectsToRotateLeft %= array.count;

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, numberOfObjectsToRotateLeft);
NSMutableArray * rotatedArray = [array mutableCopy];

[rotatedArray addObjectsFromArray:[rotatedArray subarrayWithRange:range]];
[rotatedArray removeObjectsInRange:range];

// now return or use rotatedArray
```

Rotate right would be similar, but the range would be at the end of the array, and you'd insert the objects starting at index 0 with `-insertObjects:atIndexes:`:

```
// Make sure we don't overrun the array if the rotation is larger.
numberOfObjectsToRotateRight %= array.count;

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(array.count - numberOfObjectsToRotateRight, numberOfObjectsToRotateRight);
NSMutableArray * rotatedArray = [array mutableCopy];

NSArray * movedObjects = [rotatedArray subarrayWithRange:range];
[rotatedArray removeObjectsInRange:range];
[rotatedArray insertObjects:movedObjects atIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, numberOfObjectsToRotateRight)]];

// now return or use rotatedArray
```